# Control AC load via relay with DC trigger?

Tags: switches, relay, dc, 12v, spdt

The headlight of my motorcycle is AC powered via stator.

I want to switch between Hi/Low beam using a single pole double throw (SPDT) NC relay.
Power to pin 30 (AC)
Ground to pin 85 (?)
Trigger to pin 86 (DC)
Output 87 Lo-beam (AC)
Output 87a Hi-beam (AC)

But I want to trigger that relay using a DC switch source (my handlebar controls are DC from the battery, and my headlight is AC from the stator.)

Can I trigger an AC relay with the DC current from my handlebar switch?
Is it better to do this with an AC or DC relay?
How do I do this simply without adding too much extra wiring to bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DC relay for this with enough current rating for the lamp, like those used in cars. The trigger source defines the coil, not the load.

Answer (score 2):

Standard 12 V DC automotive relays would do.

Two would be required, one to switch on the headlight and the other to select 'high' or 'low' beam.

[image]